# Net Core And Ajax- Not All Data Returns Successful And Slow Loading Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

4 records out of 6 records in the database return successfully. But two records are returning unsuccessful. When I look through the controller, there is no problem with the data. It also loads very slowly even though there are only 6 records. How do I solve this problem? Is there a more alternative way for me to pull the data?

[photo of incorrect data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbO8a.png)

Controller Code:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> MainCategories()
        {
            var maincategorylist = await appDbContext.BusinessMainCategories.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToListAsync();


            var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(maincategorylist, Formatting.None,
                        new JsonSerializerSettings()
                        {
                            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
                        });
            var xc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData);
            return Json(xc);
        }
```

Script Code:

```
<script>
        $("#mainCategoryList").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Admin/BusinessCategories/MainCategories/",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {
                    var item = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $("#table-maincategories").empty();

                    $.each(JSON.parse("[" + item + "]"), (index, value) => {

                        for (let element of value) {

                            $("#table-maincategories").append(`<tr class="text-center">
                            <td><img src="${element.Image}" style="height:80px;" /></td>
                            <td>${element.Name}</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <a href="/Admin/BusinessCategories/MainShowMenu/${element.Id}" onclick="location.href=this.href;">
                                        <input checked="${element.ShowMenu}" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flex_${element.Id}">
                                    </a>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flex_${element.Id}">Menüde Göster</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="EditMainCategory" asp-route-id="${element.Id}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bx bx-edit"></i> Düzenle</a>
                                <a asp-action="DeleteMainCategory" asp-route-id="${element.Id}" data-name="${element.Name}" class="btn btn-danger delete-button"><i class="bx bx-trash"></i> Sil</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>`);

                        }

                    });
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your question is either about ASP or jQuery. It can't really be both. Where is the problem? Have you debugged the response? Also, don't show data or code as images. That's not data anyway. It's a web page.

Comment: No error is returned in the console. That's why I didn't add the console output.

Comment: I said the response, not errors. You should be able to output data on the backend to a log, and you should be able to set breakpoints in the browser for that data.

Comment: I did not understand what you said. Do you want to see the dataset returned by the Controller when I go directly to the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It also loads very slowly even though there are only 6 records. How do
> I solve this problem? Is there a more alternative way for me to pull
> the data?

Well, reason for slow loading data is pretty obvious. You have couple of unnecessary both in `controller` and importantly in `javascript` which causing the issue.

For instance, when you use `JsonResult` and `Json()` you don't need to explicitely parse your json again like this way.`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` here also time factor comes in because conversion means `big O`.

So you can do directly like this:

**Controller Slowness:**

```
public async Task<JsonResult> MainCategories()
        {
            var categoryList = new List<CategoryTest>()
            {
                new CategoryTest(){ Id = 1, Name = "A",ShowMenu = true, Image ="Image-1"},
                new CategoryTest(){ Id = 2, Name = "B",ShowMenu = true, Image ="Image-2"},
                new CategoryTest(){ Id = 3, Name = "C",ShowMenu = true, Image ="Image-4"},
                new CategoryTest(){ Id = 4, Name = "D",ShowMenu = true, Image ="Image-5"},


            };
            return Json(categoryList);
        }
```

**Data Output:**

[image]

**Client Side(Javascript) Slowness:**

Now let's look at your `javascript/jQuery` code snippet"

The controller already return the data as json. But what are you doing here:

```
var item = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Then again:   `$.each(JSON.parse`

Do you know the how costly it is? Have you heard of `Big O`? It will cost `O(n^2)`.

**Efficient Way:**

```
<div>
    <table id="table-maincategories">
    </table>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Admin/BusinessCategories/MainCategories/",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#table-maincategories").empty();
                    //Its already in json so no need to parse again
                    $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                        console.log(element.id);
                        $("#table-maincategories").append(`<tr class="text-center">
                                                        <td><img src="${element.Image}" style="height:80px;" /></td>
                                                        <td>${element.Name}</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                                <a href="/Admin/BusinessCategories/MainShowMenu/${element.Id}" onclick="location.href=this.href;">
                                                                    <input checked="${element.ShowMenu}" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flex_${element.Id}">
                                                                </a>
                                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="flex_${element.Id}">Menüde Göster</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <a asp-action="EditMainCategory" asp-route-id="${element.Id}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bx bx-edit"></i> Düzenle</a>
                                                            <a asp-action="DeleteMainCategory" asp-route-id="${element.Id}" data-name="${element.Name}" class="btn btn-danger delete-button"><i class="bx bx-trash"></i> Sil</a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>`);
                    });
                }
            })

        });
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** You can see only one each loop `$.each(data, function (index, element) {}` is enough what you are trying to achieve

**Reason For Undefined:**

Here, debugging will be your savior. From your details its hard to know the reason. You can debug as below:

[image]

**Note:** As your reason is unknown so debug will provide you the clue why only two data is not loading.

Comment: Please pardon, I don't really get what did you mean, even not sure the language. Would you kindly post new question  if you still have any concern, I would love to assist on that.

Comment: Here is the title of my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74783069/ajax-datatable-not-nowrking