# Ajax- DataTable Not Nowrking

Tags: ajax, datatable, datatables

I'm processing the incoming data with Ajax as follows. But I can't make it compatible with dataTable. I've read the Datatable Ajax documentation. But I was never successful. How do I pull the following data into the dataTable? I want to make these codes compatible for Data Table.

You can see multiple parse operations in my code. Please do not warn about it. Net Core, I can only process the JSON file in this way. The only thing I want from you is to show this data that I have processed successfully in the datatable.

```
<div class="card" id="view-maincategorylist">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="datatablex" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Fotoğraf</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Ana Kategori Adı</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Seçenekler</th>
                        <th class="text-center">İşlemler</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table-maincategories">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script>

        function GetMainCategoryList() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Admin/BusinessCategories/MainCategories/",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {
                    var item = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $("#table-maincategories").empty();

                    $.each(JSON.parse("[" + item + "]"), (index, value) => {

                        for (let element of value) {

                            $("#table-maincategories").append(`<tr class="text-center">
                                                        <td><img src="${element.Image}" style="height:80px;" /></td>
                                                        <td>${element.Name}</td>
                                                        <td>
                                                             <div class="form-check">
                                                             <a href="/Admin/BusinessCategories/MainShowMenu/${element.Id}" onclick="location.href=this.href;">
                                                             <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flex_${element.Id}">
                                                             </a>
                                                             <label class="form-check-label" for="flex_${element.Id}">Menüde Göster</label>
                                                             </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                             <a onclick="ShowEditMainCategory(${element.Id})" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bx bx-edit"></i> Düzenle</a>
                                                             <a onclick="DeleteMainCategory(${element.Id});" data-name="${element.Name}" id="del_${element.Id}" class="btn btn-danger delete-button"><i class="bx bx-trash"></i> Sil</a>
                                                        </td> </tr>`);

                            var checkbox = document.getElementById('flex_' + element.Id);
                            if (element.ShowMenu == true) {
                                checkbox.checked = true;
                            }
                            else {
                                checkbox.checked = false;
                            }
                        }

                    });

                    $('#datatable').DataTable();
                    ViewShowHide(1);
                },

                error: function () {
                    Swal.fire('Veriler Okunamadı!', '', 'error')
                }
            })

        }
    </script>
```

Problem Images:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBB7O.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isoWd.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJnvn.png)

JSON Data Output:
https://easyupload.io/1bsb75

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show us the JSON data (as formatted text)? See [mre] for more detailed guidance. Can you also specify what _specific_ error you are getting (e.g. in the browser console) or what _specific_ behavior you are seeing? What does "not working" mean, precisely?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you have to build a HTML string from the JSON data (but a MRE may make this clearer). I know you said "_Please do not warn about it._" But here I am, warning you about it, anyway. This approach appears to be fighting against DataTables, instead of working with it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your help and suggestion. Actually, there is no sample code that I wrote about Datatable. I am not getting any errors. You see how I receive and process JSON data. What I want to do is how can I show this data in dataTable? Currently, records as <td> are added and displayed in the table as it is. But dataTable search is not working. Datatab total record count not working. Datatable paging is not working. For example, if there are 500 records, all of them are displayed and paging does not work.......

Comment: In short these dataTable properties are not working for me. As you know, dataTable prepares the table with the document.ready function and renders it as a datatable. However, when I take the data this way and insert it into <td> rows, there is no difference between a static table and a datatable table. Here is my problem. I don't have a code sample because I don't know how to process this data for datatable. I have attached pictures explaining my problem. When you look at those pictures, you will understand my problem. I would really apreciate if you help.

Comment: You said "_You see how I receive and process JSON data_". Yes, I do see - it's right there in your question. But what I asked was: "_Can you [edit] the question to show us the JSON data (as formatted text)?_" The reason for asking is described in [mre].

Comment: I have uploaded the Json data file. Could you please look at the Json file from the link I added? I hope I understood you correctly. I added a JSOn data output

Comment: Sorry, no. I am not going to click on a link to some external site - and that is not even necessary. Please **show us the JSON data (as formatted text)**. Bear in mind you only need to show us a **minimal** sample, if you are concerned about the amount of data (please re-read [mre]). As long as you show us the overall structure of your JSON, and include some sample rows, then that is exactly what a MRE is all about.